# Nested framework not working in nginx

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, frameworks

In my web app i have two nested  framework installed. One is developed my own and another is codeigniter. My own framework is on the top and codeigniter is inside it. My framework works fine but when i login from my codeigniter it doesnot work perfectly. Same as if codignitor is in top and my framework is inside codeignitor works fine and mine does not. Why is this happening? Is there any problem with my server configuration file? Code of server configuration file is

```
server {

    root /usr/share/nginx/www/EducationPortal;
    index index.php;

    if (!-d $request_filename){
        set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename){
        set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
    }
    if ($request_filename !~ "-l"){
        set $rule_0 3$rule_0;
    }
    if ($rule_0 = "321"){
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename){
        set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
    }
    if (!-d $request_filename){
        set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
    }
    if ($rule_0 = "21"){
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to index.html
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
        # For example, return an error code
        #return 418;
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }


    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

Is there any way to make this work??

Comment: What are those rule rewrites supposed to be doing....? They are the first thing to delete if you're looking to clean up your nginx config - see [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

Comment: Because i have .htaccess file in both framework

Comment: I don't know what you wish to say with that, nginx does not read `.htaccess` files.

Comment: I know nginx dont read those files. And those rewrite rules are converted from htaccess fils because without these rules app will not work. I think u understand what i mean

Comment: htaccess->nginx converter script things always result in an utter mess IME - the config in the question is a case in point. You haven't explained what your config is supposed to be doing - Good luck :).

Comment: I still dont understand what u mean :(